# CodeIgniter model works in localhost not in live

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, model

Every thing works fine in localhost, but when I upload on server, login view is getting opened but, while in checklogin when I try to load model I am getting bellow error

> Unable to locate the model you have specified: loginmodel

controller file: **login.php**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function checkLogin() {
        $this->load->model('loginModel');
....
```

model file: **loginModel.php**

```
    class LoginModel extends CI_Model {
```

config file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://myattendance.co.nf/';
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# FOR LIVE
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

# FOR LOCAL
    #RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: change $this->load->model('loginModel'); to $this->load->model('LoginModel');

Comment: which codeigniter version u r using ?

Comment: Read this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming `Login_model.php` and `class Login_model extends CI_Model {}` Only the first letter should be upper case on file and class name

Comment: in controller anywhere you may call like this...`$this->loginmodel->function_name()`....change it to `$this->loginModel->function_name()`.

Comment: 2.2.6 @dhruv jadia

Comment: change class LoginModel extends CI_Model to class loginModel extends CI_Model

Comment: it is loginModel already @dhruvjadia

Comment: file name same as class name

Comment: still didn't work@dhruvjadia

Comment: changed file name to Loginmodel.php didn't work@wolfgang1983

Comment: @MohammediComputers try some of these htaccess https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter is your models in the models folder http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/models.html

Comment: yes model is inside models folder - tried three of the given .htacess :( @wolfgang1983

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter 3+ requires First letter of your class file capital in linux machine. I think your live server is a linux machine and you are developing in windows machine. Just simply rename all of your class files (Controller, Model and Libraries) to first letter capital. eg: rename your model `loginModel.php` to `LoginModel.php`

Hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: I am using 2.2.6, yesterday already tried by renaming files as @wolfgang1983 said by user guide link

Comment: Don't know where I am making mistake

Comment: login_model.php    class login_model
login_view.php       class login_view
etc

Answer (score 0):

php version may be different on server and local so please make class name and file name same. for example If Your class LoginModal then its file name should be LoginModal.php also same for controller class.

Comment: tried both are now same file name and class name is LoginModel but same error

Comment: Your controller name should be Login.php and your modal name should be LoginModal.php

Answer (score 0):

Change the model's file name, model file: `loginModel.php` to model file: `Loginmodel.php`,then change the name of the model's class name as well from `class LoginModel extends CI_Model{}` to `class Loginmodel extends CI_Model{}` then refresh your link, it will work.